# Segmentation fault when starting Kodi after updating Fedora 35 along with the Nvidia driver

Tags: linux, fedora, kodi, flatpak

Kodi stopped working after updating Fedora 35. The update included new kernel and NVidia Driver version. It just won't open and the only significant error I find in the logs is:

```
/app/bin/kodi: line 187:     7 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ${KODI_BINARY} $SAVED_ARGS
```

System

- OS: Fedora 35
- Video card: NVidia GeForce GTX 750Ti
- Kodi installation: Using flatpak - tv.kodi.Kodi

I tried everything I found on Google. Since a lot of people say that it must be related to NVidia, I:

- Updated the Nvidia driver
- Downgraded the Nvidia driver
- Manually installed the Nvidia driver, switched back and forth between this one and the akmod-nvidia.
- Tried switching back to previously installed kernel versions
- Tried switching back and forth on Gnome Xorg and Gnome wayland.

It finally worked using Wayland in a specific situation but it is because Kodi couldn't use the Nvidia driver. The performance was terrible but this tells me that it must be because of this driver.

I also tried

- Reinstalling Kodi
- Deleting all of its addons
- Reinstalling previous version of Kodi using flatpak update --commit ...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there are old nvidia "drivers" or "bindings" installed in flatpak that don't match the actual Nvidia driver installed on the computer. (`NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-510.60.02`)

Reinstalling tv.kodi.Kodi wouldn't trigger the installation of the correct flatpak Nvidia package.

I had to uninstall the mismatching Nvidia packages in flatpak and then simply reinstall Kodi. It automatically installed the matching Nvidia package.

What I had before the manipulation (`flatpak list`):

```
nvidia-470-74                          org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-470-74                                   1.4         user
nvidia-470-86                          org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-470-86                                   1.4         user
```

I removed both of them

```
flatpak remove org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-470-74
flatpak remove org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-470-86
```

I reinstalled Kodi

```
flatpak install kodi
```

And now it works. I can see the matching Nvidia package in `flatpak list` and Kodi is working perfectly:

```
nvidia-510-60-02                       org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-510-60-02                              1.4         user
```